# Does Meteor.call in server side without callback block server?

Tags: meteor

For example:

`server/method.js`

```
Meteor.methods({
  insertPost: function(post) {
      //call another method
      var ret = Meteor.call('longTimeMethod', post.data); // A
      // ...
   }
 })
```

Meteor doc says

> If you do not pass a callback on the server, the method invocation will block until the method is complete.

since nodejs is single thread, if `A` costs 60 seconds, the whole server will not response to any requests during this 60s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not the whole server will block, only the fiber running for this particular client. If you don't want that, then you can simply call `this.unblock()` before your method call, and a new fiber will be used for future method calls from that client, see http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/method_unblock.